# ionic 3 and woocommerce rest api post requet error

Tags: wordpress, angular, woocommerce, ionic3

i'm working on an ionic 3 app that connect to a woocommerce (wordpress) rest api, all GET requests works fine but only POST requests not working:

here an image of the error message:
[image: console log]

init code of the woocommerce module:

```
this.WooCommerce = WC({
  url: "http://*******.com",
  consumerKey: "ck_*********************",
  consumerSecret: "cs_***********************",
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v2'
});
```

and the post call is :

```
this.WooCommerce.postAsync("customers", datac).then( (data) => .....
```

my question is is there is a config on the server or anything else to fix this, keep in mindGET requests works fine ?

Comment: ok just solved it by changing api version to v2 and test on device.don't know why but it works

Comment: I'm facing similar issue ,when i run my app in browser by disabling security in chrome post request works fine,but when i test this on my device it return the similar error.The get request works fine in both the cases.